# Remove CheckListBox CheckedItems

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a timer event that does several things. One item I am trying to get it to do is to programmatically remove the `CheckListBox` items that are checked once the timer hits the completed action I am performing.

This is the code for the timer and what I have tried to do.

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string s;
    if (DbFirmwareUpdateComplete.WaitOne(1))
    {
        DbFirmwareUpdateComplete.Reset();
        mnuLoadKeyFile.Enabled = true;
    }

    if (DbUpdateComplete.WaitOne(1))
    {
        DbUpdateComplete.Reset();
        mnuLoadKeyFile.Enabled = true;
        btnLoad.Enabled = true;
    }
    if (CacheComplete.WaitOne(1))
    {
        CacheComplete.Reset();
        btnLoad.Enabled = true;
    }
    if (UpdateRunning)
    {
        bool UpdateDone = true;
        int StillActive = 0;
        // loop through all active jobs to check if all have completed
        foreach (clsCnaPair cna in ActiveJobs)
        {
            if (cna.Job.JobComplete == false)
            {
                UpdateDone = false;
                StillActive++;
            }

            else
            {
                if (cna.Job.UpdateSuccess)
                {
                    // Update color of CLB.Items.Selected if success.
                    int count = CLB.Items.Count;
                    for (int index = count; index > 0; index--)
                    {
                        if(CLB.CheckedItems.Contains(CLB.Items[index-1]))
                        {
                            CLB.Items.RemoveAt(index - 1);
                        }
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    // Update color of CLB.Items.Selected if failed.
                }
            }
        }
        if (UpdateDone)
        {
            UpdateRunning = false;
            log("All Update jobs have finished.");
        }
        if (ckTop.Checked == true)
        {
            ckTop.Checked = false;
        }
        else
        {
            ckTop.Checked = false;
        }
```

When I run the program and it hits this piece;

```
        if (cna.Job.UpdateSuccess)
        {
            // Update color of CLB.Items.Selected if success.
            int count = CLB.Items.Count;
            for (int index = count; index > 0; index--)
            {
                if(CLB.CheckedItems.Contains(CLB.Items[index-1]))
                {
                    CLB.Items.RemoveAt(index - 1);
                }
            }
        }
```

I get an error:

> System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: InvalidArgument=Value of '-1' is not valid for 'index'.
>   Parameter name: index

The Error occurs after this piece of code;

```
private void CLB_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // One of the CNA IPs was selected. sender is the CheckedListBox.
    // Here we want to display its fingerprint in the text box, or if the push is running, the status.

    // get the CnaPair class represented by this IP:
    clsCnaPair CnaPair = (clsCnaPair)CLB.Items[CLB.SelectedIndex];

    // Display the corresponding fingerprint string in the editBox:
    if (CnaPair.Job != null) txtStatus.Text = CnaPair.Job.GetStatus();
    else txtStatus.Text = CnaPair.GetInfo();
}
```

Or more specifically at the line:

```
clsCnaPair CnaPar = (clsCnaPair)CLB.Items[CLB.SelectedIndex];
```

What am I missing? Searching google, shows the way I am doing the remove is consistent with the examples found there.

Thanks,

Comment: ... error said more than enough. Read it out loud and then try to replace your code with values that caused the problem `clsCnaPair CnaPair = (clsCnaPair)CLB.Items[-1]` Now check what you get.

Comment: m.rogalski, it gives the same error message.

Comment: @m.rogalski has pointed you in the correct direction, Check that CLB.SelectedIndex >= 0.

Comment: Just to be clear here. Should I be modifying this line:

clsCnaPair CnaPar = (clsCnaPair)CLB.Items[CLB.SelectedIndex];

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's dangerous to modify the contents of the ChecklistBox inside a loop when the loop conditions depend on the contents of the ChecklistBox. Once you call RemoveAt(), the CheckedItems list and the CLB.Items.Count has changed and you will have a problem. In this case, the loop fired the SelectedIndexChanged() event with an invalid Index (-1).

Better to do this in a do-while loop:

```
bool done;
do
{
    done = true;
    for (int index = CLB.Items.Count; index > 0; index--)
    {
        if(CLB.CheckedItems.Contains(CLB.Items[index-1]))
        {
            CLB.Items.RemoveAt(index - 1);
            done = false;
            break;
        }
    }

}while(!done);
```

This way, every time an item is removed, you break out and start the loop all over again.

Answer (score 0):

After some experimentation, I commented out the CLB_SelecteIndexChanged code and it now completes with the original code.

That leaves one issue. What is the work around with the CLB_SelectedIndexChanged code left in. I will work on that one more and see f I can figure it out with what you guys have provided.

Thanks to both m.rogalski and mcNets.

Comment: Adding if (CLB.SelectedIndex == -1) return; just before the clsCnaPair CnaPair = (clsCnaPair)CLB.Items[CLB.SelectedIndex}; line, stops the error.

Comment: Adding a bool, do/while wrapper and changing the int index = to CLB.Items.Count vice index = count is the other item changed. All works great now.